# How to display the entire line with [grep] matching the pattern?

Tags: grep, pattern-matching

How to display the entire line with `grep` matching the pattern?

example.log:

```
8.8.8.8 [24/May/2020:10:10:10] TLSv1.2 302
8.8.8.8 [24/May/2020:10:10:11] TLSv1.3 200
8.8.8.8 [24/May/2020:10:10:12] TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
8.8.8.8 [24/May/2020:10:10:12] TLSv1.1 200
8.8.8.8 [24/May/2020:10:10:13] TLSv1 200
8.8.8.8 [24/May/2020:10:10:13] TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
8.8.8.8 [24/May/2020:10:10:14] TLSv1 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

How to display the entire line that has the `TLSv1` pattern only? If I use `grep -e 'TLSv1` it will display the other lines as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
grep 'TLSv1 '
```

Note the space in the regex

or

```
grep 'TLSv1\s'
```

or using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '$3=="TLSv1"'
```

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to mention that the `TLSv1` pattern is not the last field in the file. Updated my question